# Create "copy" of FILE* state

Tags: c, file

I want to something like this:

```
char* parse_path(FILE* original_state) {
    FILE* copied_state = copyfp(original_state);
    // logic for reading the path
    if (error) {
        return NULL;
    }
    else {
        somehow_set_state(original_state, copied_state);
        return path;
    }
}

int main() {
    FILE* fp = open("file_with_or_without_path.txt");
    if (fd == NULL) return 1;
    char* path = parse_path(fd);
    if (path != NULL)
        printf("path fould: %s\n", path);
    else
        printf("no path found\n");
    ...
}
```

So basically I want to copy the state of a `FILE*` and modify it (like read or seek) and being able to write the new state to the other `FILE*` in case parsing was a success. I could remember the current cursor location and seek back later, but that would make my code a lot more complex. So I was wondering, can I

Comment: Your "save and seek" approach would certainly add some lines, but I don't think it would qualify as "a lot more complex".  If the issue is you need to do it in a number of places, make *save* and *restore* functions.

Comment: As for the "complexity" issue, that's not too bad. And it's also *very* clear to the readers what's going on and what the code is doing. A comment on the "why" part might be needed though.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think that is not a good Idea, because the FILE* contains multiple buffers that wouldn't be freed if one of them is reallocated

Comment: You can't make a copy of a `FILE`.  It's just about guaranteed not to work.  If you need to save and restore your *position* in the file, then yes, that's what `ftell` and `fseek` are for.

Comment: I think basically impossible with standard C.  also you're going to have to choose between `open()` and `fopen()`.  Picking an operating system would probably help too.

Comment: @Jasen that is the thing, I want to do it with stdio functions to make it portable. With raw file descriptors that wouldn't be a problem - I would need to use seek anyway

Comment: ftell won't get you all the state eg: state pushed using ungetc() and also state created by the use of read() or write() on "r+" or "w+" files which stat is cleared when fseek() is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy the state of a FILE* object. You can copy the FILE* object itself, but that's not what you want. You want to copy the state of the underlying file descriptor. You can do that with dup() or dup2().

Comment: This is not what I want, because I can not assume, that every system uses file descriptors. For example, Windows has the the stdio functions, but does not use file descriptors.